# Javascript (Underscore), function to change javascript object

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

Trying to change an object to prepare it for send by taking the array inside and turning it into an object with the items in the array being keys with values of true.

It starts out looking like -

```
  {"state":["Saved","Published"],"discipline":["Marketing"]}
```

So the end result would look like

```
  {"state":{"Saved":true,"Published":true},"discipline":{"Marketing":true}}
```

So it just looks at that array and changes it to an object with values of true. I am trying to use underscore but plain js would work just fine.

Here is my attempt, is there a better way to do this, maybe with underscore? -

```
 function transformOutputToFilterModel(model) {

                var transformedObj = _.map(model, function(obj) {
                    return obj.reduce(function(obj, k) {
                      obj[k] = true;
                      return obj;
                    }, {})
                });
               return transformedObj;

            }
```

Thanks for reading!

Edit - sorry I had marked an answer wihtout realizing it wasn't exactly corret. I have this function -

```
  var transformedObj = _.map(model, function(obj) {
                    return obj.reduce(function(obj, k) {
                        obj[k] = true;
                        return obj;
                    }, {});
                });
```

this does format the inside object correctly, however it is pulling off the outer keys - see here : https://jsfiddle.net/d0kjctfh/3/

Those outer objecst should have the keys of state and discipline like this -

```
{"state":{"Saved":true,"Committed":false,"Published":false},"discipline":{"Marketing":true}};
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think _.map will always return an array so its not the best solution. Try the code bellow.

```
var t = {"state":["Saved","Published"],"discipline":["Marketing"]},
newObj = {};

_.each(t, function(obj, index) {    
    newObj[index] = {};
    if(_.isArray(obj)){ 
        var toReturn = {};
        _.each(obj, function(index,item){
            toReturn[index] = true;
        });     
        newObj[index] = toReturn;
    }
});
console.log(newObj);
```

Comment: ended up using this, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You need to do it in several steps:

```
_.mapObject(model, function(vals) { 
     return _.object(vals, _.map(vals, function() { return true; }));
 } );
```

The map just makes a list of `true`s the right length, the _.object changes `["Saved","Published"]` into `{"Saved":true,"Published":true}` and the _.mapObject applies it to every field.

Answer (score 1):

No need for underscore; Array.map() is native Javascript. However, map returns an array, which isn't what you want. Try reduce, accumulating the results into an (initially) empty object:

```
var input = {"state":["Saved","Published"],"discipline":["Marketing"]};


var toObject = function(arr) {
    return arr.reduce(function(prev,curr){
        prev[curr]=true;   
        return prev;
    },{});
}

console.log(toObject(input.state));
```

Comment: You got there on your own while I was typing!

Comment: This doesn't add the outer state and discipline on

Comment: Correct - I left off the outer loop to just show the interesting bit.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes the easiest way is the classic way:

```
function prepareObject(obj){
    var i, e, o = {};
    for(e in obj){
        if(obj.hasOwnProperty(e)){
                o[e] = {};
                for(i = 0; i <= obj[e].length - 1; i++) {
                    obj[e][obj[e][i]] = true;
                }
        }
    }
    return o;
}
```

Optimized / minify

window.prepareObject=function(b){var c,a,d={};for(a in b)if(b.hasOwnProperty(a))for(d[a]={},c=0;c<=b[a].length-1;c++)b[a][b[a][c]]=!0;return d};

Answer (score 1):

```js
var input = {"state":["Saved","Published"],"discipline":["Marketing"]};
    
    
    function childToObj(arr) {
        return arr.reduce(function(prev,curr){
            prev[curr]=true;   
            return prev;
        },{});
    }
    

for (var key in input) {
  if (input.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    input[key] = childToObj(input[key]);
  }
}
    
    
    
    console.log(input);
    console.log(JSON.stringify(input));
```